# Unable to register for push notifications on Android in Xamarin together with IntercomIO

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, intercom

I added the IntercomIO SDK to our Xamarin.Forms app through a couple binding libraries this week and I'm currently trying to get the Push Notifications to work but soon after I call PushHandlerService.Register(this) in the MainActivity the app crashes saying that it can't find the class com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver which isn't even being caught by the try catch block around this call.

Here is the method inside the MainActivity which is responsible for setting up the push notifications on Android.

```
    public void registerForPushNotifications()
    {
        try
        {
            GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
            GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);

            //Register the app for push notifications.
            PushHandlerService.Initialize(this);

            //if (!GcmClient.IsRegistered(this))//Temporarily force the app to register for push notifications
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Registering");

                // Register for GCM
                PushHandlerService.Register(this);
            }

            LocalBroadcastManager lbc = LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this);
            PushActionReceiver rec = new PushActionReceiver(this);
            lbc.RegisterReceiver(rec, new IntentFilter("pushaction"));
        }
        catch (Java.Net.MalformedURLException)
        {
            var e = new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail(String.Format(@"Exception at {0}: {1}", this.GetType().Name, e.Message));
            Insights.Report(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail(String.Format(@"Exception at {0}: {1}", this.GetType().Name, e.Message));
            if (e.GetType() != typeof(TaskCanceledException))
                Insights.Report(e);
        }
    }
```

And in the Manifest I added the receiver definition for Intercom

```
<receiver android:name="io.intercom.android.sdk.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"></receiver>
```

The issue doesn't happen when I don't call PushHandlerService.Register(this) but then obviously I can't receive any push notifications anymore (including the ones from our own system)

What's going on here? I have the libraries and dependancies setup properly but it doesn't seem to be able to find the GcmReceiver class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently updating to the latest SDK's in the SDK Manager solved this crash. I am still not receiving any push notifications but I'm guessing this is due to a different issue. At least the app doesn't crash anymore when trying to register for the push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Dale from Intercom here. Are you using any other third party push providers, or do you have your own GCM receiver? It's possible that they are consuming our push and not passing them on. This can be difficult in Xamarin, Phonegap, Cordova ect. as often the registration and receiver services are not available. I have included below a link to our GCM doc and the section that may be most relevant to you. If this doesn't help fix the issue get in touch with us on the cordova repo: https://github.com/intercom/intercom-cordova or reach out to us in your Intercom dashboard/ email us at team@intercom.io.

We have GCM docs here: https://docs.intercom.com/configure-intercom-for-your-product-or-site/configure-intercom-for-mobile/enable-push-notifications-with-intercom-for-android-gcm

The issue that might be causing you difficulty in your setup is:

**Step 7. Using Intercom with other GCM setups (Optional)**

This only applies to applications that also use GCM for their own content, or use a third party service for GCM. You’ll need to update the your GcmListenerService and the class where you generate your device token.

You should have a class that generates a push device token and sends it to your backend. In addition to sending the token to your backend you will need to forward it to Intercom, like this:

```
private final IntercomPushClient intercomPushClient = new IntercomPushClient();

public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {     
    InstanceID instanceId = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String senderId = "YOUR_SENDER_ID";
    String token = instanceId.getToken(senderId,
    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
    pushClient.sendTokenToIntercom(getApplication(), token);
}
```

You should have a class that extends GcmListenerService. That service will consume pushes intended for Intercom. To allow us to draw the Intercom push set up your GcmListenerService, like this:

```
private final IntercomPushClient intercomPushClient = new IntercomPushClient();

public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle message) {
    if (intercomPushClient.isIntercomPush(message)) {
        intercomPushClient.handlePush(getApplication(), message);
    } else {
        //DO HOST LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work today, our GCM setup was uncooperative for some reason and after creating a new one (based on FCM) it started working as expected.